# Add pictureBox to List

Tags: c#, winforms, list, picturebox

In my winform app I have 3 pictureBox, and I want to add them to a List.
I tried

```
List<PictureBox> pictureBoxList = new List<PictureBox>();  

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)  
{ 
 pictureBoxList.Add((PictureBox)Controls.Find("pictureBox" +i, true)); 
}
```

I get the error

> "Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Control[]' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' "

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :** `Controls.Find()` method returns the `Control[]` Array

**Solution :** You need to Access the First Element of the Controls Array to cast it backto `PictureBox`.

Replace This:

```
pictureBoxList.Add((PictureBox)Controls.Find("pictureBox" +i, true));
```

With This:

```
pictureBoxList.Add((PictureBox)Controls.Find("pictureBox" +i, true)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LINQ` for that:

```
var pictureBoxList = this.Controls.OfType<PictureBox>()
            .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("pictureBox"))
            .ToList();
```

Your problem is [`Controls.Find`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method returns an array of controls and you are trying to cast a control array to `Picturebox`.